# Understanding Function Prototype in C

Tags: c, function

Why does the following program works fine?

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    x = foo();
    printf("%d",x);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int foo()
{
    return 2;
}
```

and not this program?

```
//double function(void);

int main(){
    double val;
    val = function();
    printf("%ul\n",val);
}

double function(void){
    double num;
    num = DBL_MAX;
    printf("%ul\n",num);
    return num;
}
```

In my understanding, definition of functions in both these cases are absent before `main()`. So why is it that in the first case the function is called anyway, even when compiler has no definition of it before `main()` and not in second case?

Comment: Note that both the old C standard (C99) and the current C standard (C11) say that the programs should generate diagnostics. Only the archaic (C89/C90) standard allows the first program to work, and the second always fails. If you like working with broken code, fine — write to the sloppier C89 standard. The lax rules were a historical necessity. The standard could not have been successful without the laxness. But the old standard is 15 years old and you should use it and make your compiler issue warnings when you use a function without a prototype. If your compiler won't, get a better compiler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , Can `%ul` be used for a `double`?

Comment: In a `printf()` format string?  No; `%ul` formats an `unsigned int` followed by a letter `l` that is not part of the conversion specification. If you meant `%lu`, that formats an `unsigned long`.  Neither is useful (or even reliable) when you pass a `double` as the corresponding value in the argument list.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , Oops! I thought that `%ul` expects an `unsigned long`. I got confused with `%ul` and `%lu`. So, are you telling that it is UB if one prints a `double` with `%lu`?

Comment: @CoolGuy: Yes, definitely UB to try printing a `double` with any integer format.  It is conceivable that floating point values are passed in separate registers from integer values, for example, so when it sees an integer format, it reads from completely the wrong place.  Computers using M68k chips used to return pointers in An registers and integers in Rn registers; if you didn't tell it that a function returned a pointer, the compiler would generate code to read from the wrong place.  I don't recall how floating point returns were handled in those chips.  Etc.

Comment: If any of the answers have been helpful to you then mark it as accepted

Answer (score 7):

Because of implicit function declaration, the compiler assumes that unspecified types are `int` by default.

In the first case that is coincidentally true, but not in the second case.

Answer (score 6):

Anything called as a function C is by default of type int, with no parameters (such as in your first case). If the compiler then finds a function which complies, there is no error.

In the second case, the compiler compiles main() thinking the function is int, but then finds it's not true, and reports an error!

COMMENT: Jonathan Leffler commented:

> Only in C89/C90. Not in C99; not in C11. Of course, some vendors still
>   only implement C89; a notable example is Microsoft!

Comment: Only in C89/C90.  Not in C99; not in C11.  Of course, some vendors still only implement C89; a notable example is Microsoft!

Comment: That's interesting! I'll add it to the reply (these comments are prone to be deleted at some time.

Answer (score 1):

In C if a function is defined then its implicit return type is `int`.

- In the first case the return type of the function is `int` so the `main()` recognizes the function and compiles without any errors.
- In second case the return type of function is `double` so the `main()` fails to recognize the function thus generating an error so you need to declare the prototype of function.

Also in older versions up till C89 if the return type is not mentioned then its is implicitly considered as `int`.

In C99 standard doesn’t allow return type to be omitted even if return type is `int`.

For more details you can check: [implicit return type C](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implicit-return-type-int-c-language/)